# Will my user ID be eventually unlinked from my community-wiki answer?

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

I posted my first `community-wiki` answer on Stack Overflow (I basically provided an image to substantiate somebody else's correct response in comments.)

It now lists community-wiki and myself as authors. Will my ID eventually disappear or is it *linked* to the answer forever?

Answer (score 7):

You are still linked to the answer as the original author.

All a community wiki does is:

1. not earn/lose you reputation from votes on that post
2. make it easier for people to edit - the reputation you need to edit (without being reviewed) is lower for CW posts at [100 points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)

If you truly want your id removed from a post then you can request that the post be disassociated from your account, but you'd need a really good reason for wanting this.